# Finding a root of a parameterized integral

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, special-functions

I have a function given as a parameterized definite integral:

```
f[a_] := Integrate[BesselJ[0, x - a] BesselJ[0, x + a], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

I suspect it has a root near `a = 0.8`. How can I evaluate this root to an arbitrary precision?

Unfortunately, *Mathematica* cannot evaluate this integral symbolically, and I don't know if it's possible at all, but I would be glad if anybody could suggest how to do it.

---

*Update:* It seems that the integral is actually divergent except some isolated values of `a` (when `a` is an odd multiple of `π/2`, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878420/19661), and it's never zero when it converges.

Comment: f[a_?NumericQ] := 
 Integrate[
  BesselJ[0, x - a] BesselJ[0, x + a], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] and then FindRoot[f[a], {a, 0.5}] ?

Comment: In V10, `NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, x - 1] BesselJ[0, x + 1], {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]` throws a `First::normal` message, which I reported.  They responded that it was a bug *and* that the integral is divergent.  They said to consider the asymptotic behavior of the Bessel functions at infinity.  But it seems to me that ignores the oscillatory behavior.  I might have time to investigate later, but I thought you probably had thought about it already.

Comment: The integral under consideration diverges for each $a>0$ since the integrand has the asymptotics $$ 2\,{\frac {\cos \left( -x+a+\pi/4 \right) \sin \left( x+a+\pi/4
 \right) }{\pi\,x}}+O \left( {x}^{-2} \right) 
$$ at infinity..

Comment: I deleted my answer. I had tried a series expansion  `ser5[x_, a_] = 
 Series[BesselJ[0, x - a] BesselJ[0, x + a], {x, Infinity, 5}] // 
   Normal // FullSimplify ` , and integration `intser[a_] = Integrate[ser5[x, a], {x, 1000, Infinity}] ` gave result, which was wrong. Integrate didn't take into accout, that integral does only converge for a - values beeing odd multiplles of Pi/4.

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir, there is one simple solution:

```
lst = Table[{a, NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, x - a] BesselJ[0,x + a], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 5, Compiled -> True]}, {a, 0.84, 0.85, 0.0001}]
```

This visualizes the result:

```
 ListPlot[lst, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["a", 16], Style["Integral", 16]}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

and should look as follows:

[image]

To vary the precision one may play with the a step and the PrecisionGoal option decreasing the former and simultaneously increasing the latter.

There is, however, a question, to what extent this estimate of the integral is correct. I tried also `Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`and it gave a very different result from the one shown above. 
I hope, my comment is useful.